# Is it possible to install kernel 3.0.0-xx in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, kernel

Its posible install the Kernel 3.0.0-xx in Precise, because I having problems with the new kernel, specially with my video card, but in oneiric with the kernel 3.0.0-26-generic-pae my video card works well.

In case I can do it, how can do it?.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refer to what the Kernel Team states about the kernel, here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel

If you want,  you can compile manually.  The Kernel Team has a wiki page about compiling the kernel: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

Its a tad hard to summarize that, but given its a common topic on kernels, it's likely not going to disappear, so there won't be a chance of that link not working.  hence the lack of a summary.